# Javascript takes effect only some specific div element

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I want to add some parameter to url when i change my skin on some wikia sites and I found some code & modified a bit

```
$("a").attr("href", function(i, href) {
    if( window.location.hostname === this.hostname ) {
        return href + "?useskin=monobook";
    }
});
```

It works pretty good. However this code adds parameter to all the links on the pages which i only want it add to link in some specific div element. Example: the links in `<div id="mw-content-text"></div>`

How can i do now? I'm still a noob with javascript. Any help is appreciated. Thank everyone.

Comment: href doesn't work on div. You have to add them on anchor only. If you want this code to run on specific anchors, then try adding a class to those specific anchors and use that class as a selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it in the selector:

```
 $("#mw-content-text a").attr("href", function(i, href) {
     if( window.location.hostname === this.hostname ) {
         return href + "?useskin=monobook";
     }
 });
```

Note that `#` reffers to a ID attribute (`<tag id="something">`) it's represented in CSS and javascript with a sharp.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. By the way, if i want to add more than one selector, how can i do? Sorry if I've troubled you. Thank you for helping me. ^ ^

Comment: You can make it with comma separated selectors `$('#id1 a , #id2 a')` but you must to take care with that. Sometimes you'll need to make a loop: `$('#some a, #some2 a').each(function() { console.log($(this)); });` Good luck